# Login failed for user '\medicallexicon_web'. Codefirst

Tags: ef-code-first

i get this error 
Cannot open database "DataLayer.Context.MedicallexiconContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'CL-xcsd-\medicallexicon_web'. 
this is my context

```
public class MedicallexiconContext : MyDbContextBase, IUnitOfWork
    {
        public DbSet<Word> Word { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Language> Language { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Picture> Picture { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RelationshipBetweenWords> RelationshipBetweenWords { get; set; }

        #region IUnitOfWork Members

        #region IUnitOfWork Members
        public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryConfig());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new WordConfig());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PictureConfig());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LanguageConfig());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RelationshipBetweenWordsConfig());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
}
```

and this is my connection string

```
  <add name="MedicallexiconContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MedicallexiconProject-2012615153521;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and this is my database name
DataLayer.Context.MedicallexiconContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an ASP.Net app is using this code?

Looks like the app pool user is `CL-xcsd-\medicallexicon_web`.  Make sure that user has appropriate permissions to the database.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(WS.10).aspx

For others that may find this... the default app pool user for IIS 7 is NETWORK SERVICE.  If you have not changed the default app pool user, this is the account that needs permission in SQL.

**Adding the user to SQL Server**

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Find your database
3. Open the Security folder under your database
4. Right-click on the Users folder (inside Security folder)
5. Select New User...
6. Click the (...) button next to Login Name
7. Click the Browse button
8. Select your user and press OK
9. Press OK again back on the Select Login dialog
10. Give your user a User Name (e.g. medicallexicon_web)
11. Check the Database Role Membership checkboxes that apply (probably db_datareader and db_datawriter)
12. Click OK

Comment: i have 4 application pool medicallexicons.com v4.0 (Integrated) medicallexicons.com v4.0 (Clasics) medicallexicons.com v2.0 (Integrated) medicallexicons.com v2.0 (Clasic).which one i have to change it?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change the application pool.  Rather, I'm suggesting that you make sure that the user `CL-xcsd-\medicallexicon_web` has permission to log into your SQL Server database.  It looks like it does not.

Comment: but i dont have medicallexicon_web user in database

Comment: i go to server manager and found medicallexicon_web but i dont know how

Comment: I added instructions on adding a new user to my answer.